# $A\in R^{n\times n}$ is diagonalizable. Prove that $A^2+3I$ is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

So I'm having a lot of trouble with the proof. I see that $A^2+3I$ is diagonalizable, but not how to move on to it being invertible. Any direction would be appreciated!

Comment: Say for instance $A$ is already diagonal, then can you prove it?

Comment: So I got to the proof that A is already diagonal (using $A^{k}v=\lambda^{k}v$ and $v\cdot p(A)=v\cdot p(A))$ not sure where to go from there

Comment: Once you prove it in the case that $A$ is diagonal, reduce the general case to that one.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by this

Comment: Is it diagonalizable over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: @ian see my answer. that is the real question

Comment: @ian, I assume over R since there is no option to disprove

Answer (score 0):

Depends upon your meaning for "diagonalizable"
$$
A =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & -2 \\
2 & -1
\end{array}
\right)
$$
This one diagonalizes as 
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
i \sqrt 3 & 0 \\
0 & - i \sqrt 3
\end{array}
\right)
$$
and
$$ A^2 + 3 I = 0  $$

Comment: Not sure how your case helps \left(
\begin{array}{rr}
1 & -2 \\
2 & -1
\end{array}
\right)+3I is invertible

Comment: @CluelessButCurious this $A$ is diagonalizable. But $A^2 + 3 I$ is not invertibl. That is what you asked about

Comment: I assumed from $A\in R^{n\times n}$ that $D\in R^{n\times n}$ since there is no option to disprove (they would give if possible)

Comment: @CluelessButCurious In that case consider that the eigenvalues of $A^2+3I$ are $\lambda^2+3$ for each eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$. This has no real zeros.

Comment: how do I show that $\lambda \ne -3$?

Comment: @CluelessButCurious $\lambda^2$, not $\lambda$...

Comment: I do not get why this answer has been downvoted, so I counter-act with a (+1). As stated, OP's claim is wrong: there are diagonalizable matrices $A$ such that $A^2+3I$ *is not* invertible. (In the original problem, $A$ is probably symmetric, too)

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is diagonal, then $A^2+3I$ is also diagonal. Invertibility of $A^2+3I$ depends on that the diagonal entries are nonzero, and...

If $A=P^{-1}DP$ for a diagonal matrix $D$, then $A^2+3I=P^{-1}(D^2+3I)P$, and so...

Comment: So I was able to get this far. how do I prove that $\lambda \ne -3$

Comment: @CluelessButCurious $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$? Actually, you can have $\lambda=-3$. The case $A=-3I$ makes $A$ diagonalisable and $A^2+3I$ is invertible.

Comment: Oh I think this answers my questions. since $\sqrt{-3}$ isn't in R!

Comment: @CluelessButCurious: this does not answer your question, since the eigenvalues of a real matrix are not compelled to be real numbers. Consider the matrix associated to a rotation in $\mathbb{R}^3$, for instance.